# Is there another way of saying "opener" as in the one who does the opening prayer in a devotion?

Tags: expressions, synonyms

Another term for saying "Opener" in a Christian devotion.

Comment: I will enquire more about it and let you know. keep learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The opening prayer in a Christian devotion is usually called "the invocation".  I have never heard the term "the invocator".  I have heard, "She will lead the invocation" or "He will give the invocation".

Answer (score 1):

precentor - a person who leads a congregation in its singing or prayers.

cantor and chorister are other words you might wanna consider.

cantor - 1.choir leader
2 : a synagogue official who sings or chants liturgical music and leads the congregation in prayer

chorister - A person who leads the singing of a church choir or congregation

Comment: My question is: How do you call a person who does the opening prayer in a devotion. Can that be called 'precentor'? Mostly He may not be the one who leads the devotion.

Comment: Yes, he can be called a precentor (because a devotion is an act, usually a prayer, or song or something else).

Comment: The chairperson stands up and says, "Now, let's call upon the precentor(in stead of saying opener)". Is this sentence correct?

Comment: yes, the message will be delivered and the implications will be understood. if there isn't a church-authorized term for it, then precentor will do.

Comment: The compound noun 'worship leader' is now well established; it probably derives from 'Would you lead us in worship on Sunday, Angela(?)' 'Lead [us] in prayer is also quite acceptable, so 'prayer leader' may be on its way. A snag is that 'worship leader' is an obviously important position needing not just any believer, whereas all members of a congregation should be able to lead prayers – 'prayer leader' would be less of a ministry description, more a localised, one-off description, and might not sound right.